# String to Date conversion not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

why is this not working, 
the string in data is typically  `movement at:2014-12-01T07:53:08`

```
var temp1 = evt.data;
var temp2 = temp1.replace("movement at:", "");
document.getElementById('movementlabel').innerHTML = temp2;
alert(temp2);
var MovementtDate=New Date(temp2);
alert(MovementtDate);
```

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What does it print and what did you expect it to print? Errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldnt be `New`. Its `new`!

```js
var temp1 = "movement at:2014-12-01T07:53:08";
var temp2 = temp1.replace("movement at:", "");
document.getElementById('movementlabel').innerHTML = temp2;
alert(temp2);
var MovementtDate= new Date(temp2);
alert(MovementtDate.getMonth()); // check the month
```

```html
<p id="movementlabel"></p>
```

Read about [new operator | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).